# SQL query: How to join two tables with common column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

i would like to join two tables that have a common column for example "custcode". The table "customer" is filled with some customer data and the table "customer_address" with the customer addresses.Basically I would like to join the data of these tables so that I can export it.

here is a query that I have tried

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "customer"
  INNER JOIN 'customer_address' ON 'customer'.'custcode' = 'customer'.'custcode'
LIMIT
  1000
```

Comment: replace * with a list of actual columns, such like customer.name and customer_address.name, prepended with the table.

Comment: Your `ON` is referencing the same table twice (ie, customer). To prevent errors and improve readability, alias your table names. `select c.col1, a.col4 from customer c join customer_address a on c.custcode = a.custcode`

Comment: at least on some databases select tableOne.*, tableTwo.* will work, but this is ugly.

Comment: And you can name the columns using "as", such like select customer.name as employ, customer_address. name as company_name

Answer (score 4):

The JOIN condition is not correct, you're referencing the table "customer" twice. You have to reference the other table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
  INNER JOIN customer_address 
    ON customer.custcode = customer_address.custcode 
LIMIT 1000; -- you want an ORDER BY as well, to avoid random results
```

Another option is to use USING():

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
  INNER JOIN customer_address USING(custcode) 
LIMIT 1000;
```

You don't need, nor want, double quotes " around your object names. Single quotes ' are used for content, not for object names.

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided has a couple of issues. First, you should use backticks (`) or square brackets ([ ]) to escape column and table names with spaces or special characters, not single quotes (' '). Second, it seems like you are using single quotes around the table names 'customer' and 'customer_address,' which would treat them as string literals, not table names

Comment: You are correct that on your second point that tick marks (single quotes) designate literal values. However the first point that you should *backticks (`) or square brackets ([ ])* for names with spaces or special characters is incorrect. In Postgres you **must use** double quotes (**"**) for this purpose.